# How do you know when to start varying your routine?

Tags: periodization

These are some of the following variables when making a routine:

- Volume
- frequency
- intensity
- range of motion
- tempo
- intensiveness
- exercise selection and order
- density and rest time

How do I know when to change the variables? If my goal is to progress faster, do I change them as I plateau or periodically regardless if I get stuck?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add. I don't workout for a particular sport. Exercising is my hobby.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't know.

There's only two certain things in exercise science

More = better

Too much = you screwed up

So you gotta find your own balance, everyone has different threshold and following a pre-made schedule means you are either doing more than you can or less than what's your true potential.

Not training enough because you follow a routine which worked on other people is wasted potential.

Training too much cause you follow someone else is probably destroy both your body and mind.

Grab a pen, paper and test yourself based on the results of others... See what routines have been tested on others and see how your results compare, then adjust it to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To quote Dan John (who I think quoted someone else)

> If you're a lawyer and you represent yourself, you have an idiot for a client. If you're a trainer and you write your own program...

How do you know when to change the variables? If you're asking the question, then you're not experienced enough to know when to change them.

Your best bet is to find a pre-written routine that matches your goals and follow it. The period of time you follow it for is determined by the program itself. If you're following a "4 weeks to bigger quadz" program, then you follow it exactly for 4 weeks. If you're following something like Jim Wendler's 5/3/1 program, then I'd say stick with it for at least 6 month, then do a more focused, set duration program, then go back to 5/3/1.

The main issue most people have is program hopping, they'll start one program and assume that it's not optimal for them and that they know better, so modify it, usually in completely stupid ways

> Your Super Squats program didn't work for me, I didn't increase my squat or put on any muscle! What? Oh, yeah, I don't like squats, so I swapped them out for leg extensions, but it's the programs fault! - Some guy on T-Nation years back

I would say you probably want a good 5 years of solid lifting experience before you even think about modifying any program you're running. And that's 5 years of following programs and progressing in some way. You need experience, a lot of experience.

Answer (score 1):

Self-evaluation should be part of any routine.  It's used to gauge whether you are reaching your goal(s).  Using your goal, you should decide what it means to “progress”.

- Is adding more sets or reps consider progress for you?
- Is adding more weight for a particular exercise progress?

Using a training journal may help you keep track of your progress.  Plan to “put in the work”.  If you train without the use of drugs, progress typically takes time.  Learn what works for you.

Lastly, it's not a bad idea to plan periodic breaks from training.  For example, you may wish to take a few days off every 6 to 8 weeks.  This break will allow you to recover from any soreness/injuries, and allow you to take stock in what progress you may have made.  Using this information will allow you to make the necessary changes to keep “progressing”.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change them if you start to get bored and not motivated to workout. New exercises tend to be more exciting and make us raring to go.

If you find that you have plateau, you can consider changing any of the variable you have mentioned. You can structure a one year plan (macro cycle) and break them up into 1 or 2 month blocks (meso cycle) and then plan the exercises you want to do.

I don’t think you need to keep changing them periodically.
Depends on your goal as well. For example, if I want to be able to hit a certain weight for bench press and I plateaued using the method of progressively adding weight every week, I’ll look at changing my reps and sets, and tempo of my lifts.